# Get a single key in place of whole object using tastypie ForeignKey

Tags: django, foreign-keys, tastypie

I'm starting with tastypie, and I'm unable to solve the following problem:

I have a series of models, linked by either ForeignKeys or ManyToMany relationships. I don't want the API to return the whole object, but rather the "id" field only.

As an example, I have the following `Taxa` model:

```
class TaxaResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    queryset = Taxa.objects.all()
    include_resource_uri = True
    resource_name = 'taxa'
```

And the `Population` model:

```
class PopulationResource(ModelResource):
taxa = fields.ForeignKey(TaxaResource, 'taxa', full=True)
class Meta:
    queryset = Population.objects.all()
    include_resource_uri = True
    resource_name = 'population'
```

I'd like the `taxa` field of `Population` objects to be `taxa.id`, not the whole `taxa` object. Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, why are you setting full=True?

```
taxa = fields.ForeignKey(TaxaResource, 'taxa', full=True)
```

Setting full=False (the default) will just return the resource URI, and you can get the id out of that.

There's a bunch of other options.

1. use `taxa = fields.IntegerProperty()` in your PopulationResource
2. in the TaxaResource, specify `fields = ['id']` to exclude everything else
3. replace the dehydrate method in PopulationResource:

.

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['taxa'] = bundle.obj.taxa_id
    return bundle
```